# Use Func<> type to assign/change variables

Tags: c#, linq

I already know that the following code doesn't work

```
string s = "";
someEnumerable.Select(x => s+= x);
```

What I want to know is if there's some other way (preferably using linq) of get the above behavior without using cyclic statements such as "for" or "foreach".

Thanks.

Comment: All LINQ does is put the "foreach" in a little helper method for you. Why are you opposed to loops?

Comment: @Eric: Just to do in one line what "foreach" does in 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string s = someIEnumerable.Aggregate((acc, next) => acc + next);
```

The acc, is the accumulator (what we've aggrigated/combined so far), next is the next element enumerated over. So, here i take what we've got so far (initially an empty string), and return the string with the next element appended.

Answer (score 2):

Or even easier, if you are only working with strings.

`var s = string.Join(string.Empty, someEnumerable)`

Comment: Thanks. However, it is not my case.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `Aggregate` or write your own ForEach extension method:

```
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T item in enumeration) { action(item); }
    }
```

and then do

```
   someEnumerable.ForEach(x => s += x);
```

Comment: (+1) Like it. Useful for more general purposes.

Comment: Note that this was purposely not included in LINQ (since LINQ queries should have no side effects).

Answer (score 0):

Literal answer:

```
string s = "";
Func<string, string> myFunc = x =>
{
  s += x;
  return x;
};

IEnumerable<string> query = source.Select(myFunc); //note, deferred - s not yet modified.
```